# Storing the value of the button

Tags: android, type-2-dimension

I  have  a  button  when  i  press  the  Button  the  value  of   the  button  should be  stored  in  a variable temporarily.And the button should remain pressed when i moved to another position using two dimensional array

Comment: Use setSelected(true); inside onclicklistener of button.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand what are you trying to do....your question is not clear...but as much as i have understand you need to use a TOGGLE BUTTON...

See below link to understand how it works:

http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-togglebutton-example/